# error: 'T' is not a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have got a following function with a use case:

```
template<size_t state_dim, size_t action_dim>
class agent {
    // [...]
    /**
     * @brief get_plugin Get a pluging by name
     */
    template<typename T>
    inline T<state_dim, action_dim>* get_plugin() const {
        const string plugin = T<state_dim, action_dim>().name();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < this->_plugins.size(); i++)
            if(this->_plugins[i].first == plugin)
                return static_cast<T<state_dim, action_dim>*>(this->_plugins.at(i).second);
        return nullptr;
    }
    // [...]
}

// a possible usecase
auto sepp = instance.get_plugin<plugin_SEP>();
```

But I get the following errors:

```
error: 'T' is not a template
    inline T<state_dim, action_dim>* get_plugin(const string& plugin) const {
           ^

error: 'T' is not a template
    return static_cast<T<state_dim, action_dim>*>(this->_plugins.at(i).second);
                       ^

error: missing template arguments before '>' token
    auto sepp = instance.get_plugin<plugin_SEP>();
                                              ^

error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
    auto sepp = instance.get_plugin<plugin_SEP>();
                                                ^
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: By `typename T` you yourself said that `T` is a *type*. Yet later you are trying to use it as a *template*. Types and templates are two completely different things. Why are you trying to use type name as a template name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.You need to declare that `T` is a [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter), otherwise you can't use(instantiate) it with template arguments.

```
template <template <size_t, size_t> class T>
inline T<state_dim, action_dim>* get_plugin(const string& plugin) const {
```

2.You need to insert keyword `template` for calling the member function template `get_plugin`.

```
auto sepp = instance.template get_plugin<plugin_SEP>();
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/3309790) for more details.

Comment: It fixed the first couple of the errors, but the last couple errors are still in effect!

Comment: @dariush Try `auto sepp = instance.template get_plugin<plugin_SEP>();`

Comment: nice, it did the job, but what the heck is that, what it's meaning?  never see this type of code before :/

Comment: @dariush See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/3309790) for more details.